# max heap and binary tree

Tags: data-structures, heap

this is an example in my data structure book and for this exercise was written that this is not a max heap,but it doesn't say its reason would you please help me that why it is not a max heap thanks.

```
       35
      /  \
     /    \
    27    28
   / \    / \
  /   \  /   \
 14   16 20   19
```

Comment: It looks like a max heap for me. Could you post all the content of this exercise? Thanks.

Comment: I wrote all its content :) but is this tree an ordered tree?

Comment: Post all the content means write what you see, not what you think it means!

Answer (score 1):

This is a heap tree, but this book is written wrong. Do not follow this book.

Comment: Please provide some explanation of why the book is wrong and what the right answer might be.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the definition of a (max) heap is that every node is bigger than all its children. And, therefore, the largest value is always at the root and therefore easy to access. This looks like a heap to me!

Comment: but it was written that it is not a heap! I do not know why? maybe it relates to binary tree!

Answer (score 0):

you should post the entire question, and if that book **actually** says that this is **not** a max-heap then stop reading that book :P

Comment: this tree is an ordered tree?

Comment: because I think that the reason relates to binary tree!